# How to wait 20 seconds after clicking element of webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, facebook, timer

Hi I have problem about my c# APP.
I want to wait 20 seconds after clicking post button in facebook group. I used this code but it is not waiting...
All links ids will be groups links in for loop. After that it will works according to the timer1_Tick method.

```
    IEnumerator<string> websites;

    
    private void button3_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       
        
        textBox4.Text = textBox3.Text;
        string[] groups = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/" + groups[0]);     

        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
       
        for(int i=1;i<groups.Length;i++)
        {
          strings.Add("https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/" + groups[i]);
        }

        websites = strings.GetEnumerator();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        websites.MoveNext();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
        
       webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0").SetAttribute("value", richTextBox2.Text);
        
       webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("view_post").InvokeMember("click");
       timer1.Interval = 20000; // This time interval is not working
       timer1.Enabled = websites.MoveNext();
    }
```

Could any body show me the error? Thanks

Comment: You are not allowed to access Facebook using any such automation, that is against their ToS. If you have a legitimate use case to automate something, then use their API.

Comment: what do you mean by timer is not working ? your timer will just make the enumerator move

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Thread.sleep(20000)` after click Post-Button in a while loop or something.

Comment: should i use a while loop?

Comment: I would do it like this but im not a very good programmer so idk :

`for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
webBrowser1.Navigate(websites.Current);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0").SetAttribute("value", richTextBox2.Text);      webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("view_post").InvokeMember("click");
Thread.sleep(20000);
}`

Comment: what is i ? i is worthless

Comment: You know how to use for loops ?
`10` is how many times you want to click it.